# CSS tips and tricks

Tags: css

I have had a little experience with CSS but am always befuddled when I come across techniques and terminology like 'liquid layouts' and 'faux columns'. I have spent considerable time reading literature on CSS but I cannot find a single comprehensive source which details all these tips & tricks (or 'hacks' as some prefer).

I have a feeling that these tips & tricks are extremely relevant if I am to become competent in web designing. Does somebody know of such a comprehensive resource?

EDIT: Thanks for the help guys. I will go through each and make a list here for everybody's reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com) always has some good stuff.  They are more like a repository for everything Design related. I find myself going there quite often if I'm trying to research something.

EDIT: Here's a link to their [CSS category](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/category/css/)

Answer (score 7):

Another great site with a ton of content is [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/) and more specifically their [page on CSS](http://www.alistapart.com/topics/code/css/)

Answer (score 3):

While it doesn't provide explanation, I often visit [CSS Zen Garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/) for ideas. It allows you to jump from page to page, keeping the same content...just changing the CSS.

Some really great examples...and you can view all the source for ideas!

Comment: +1 - css zen garden is where i got my start way back in the day

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out [CSS Beauty](http://www.cssbeauty.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

I learned something about these two common types of css selection [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744715/what-is-appropriate-ordering-of-css-selector-eg-p-class-or-class-p/4744749#4744749) recently:

Use "direct selection" `elementtype.class{}` or `elementtype#id{}` to apply style to elements directly. 
-For styling which is intended to affect once each time the rule is used eg. a margin change, a display change, a noninheriting font change. (Direct selection does not inherit to child elements, it is applied to parent element only.)

Use "descendant selection" `.class elementtype{}` or `#id elementtype` to apply style to type descendants/children of the named, or classed element. 
For styling which is intended to change appearance of elementtypes, under an element/within a section of page, where it is applied. eg. inheriting font changes to text sections, inheriting format changes to paragraphs or list elements. (Descendant selection applies to all child elements but never the parent.)

There are other useful/essential means of selection. But this is a basic distinction which it took me too long to discover.

ps. I would like to find a good css tips thread here.